# list length is wrong when using removeWhere in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Why `x` length is 4? How to get always 10? what is the reason x length is 4?

```
void main() {
  int min = 2;
  int max = 5;
  List<int> x = [];
  List<int> price = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  x = price;
  price.removeWhere((v) => min > v || max < v);
  print(x.length);// 4
  print(price);// [2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

I used this logic for `Flutter`. same issue happening in my Flutter project.

Working when added like this instead of `x = price`

```
  price.forEach((v){
    x.add(v);
  });
```

Comment: x is just another reference to price. They are the same object so what you do to one affects the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is just another reference to price. They are the same object so what you do to one affects the other. You need to use List.from to create a new list x from price.

```
x = List.from(price);
```

'List.from()
Creates a new list from the given collection.'

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert it to list

```
x = price.toList(); //<= add toList()
price.removeWhere((v) => min > v || max < v);
print(x.length);// 10
print(price);// [2, 3, 4, 5]
```